# Gzip MultipartFormDataContent Time Out When Posted To The Server

Tags: c#, .net, http, gzip

I'm trying to POST a MultipartFormDataContent in a real case scenario, a data content object could contain anything from a simple string to a video file I'm using a serialized object down there, just a proof of concept. 
Also I would like to note that using JSON objects wont serve my real life scenarios

```
 public class GzipMultipartContent : MultipartFormDataContent
 {
    public GzipMultipartContent()
    {
       Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                base.SerializeToStreamAsync(gzip, context);
        });
    }
}
```

and here's how I call it

```
var gzipped = new GzipMultipartContent();
var test = new TestClass();
gzipped.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)), "value");
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:60001/api/Home/", gzipped).Result;
```

and here's the post action in the controller

```
// POST: api/Home
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromForm] object value)
{

}
```

I have added a break point at the server side and made sure it doesn't even reach the Post method, also I have tried with a normal POST request to make sure that it's not a server configuration problem or a URL mistyping

Answer (score 2):

#### Client side

If the code in question is your real code, then there are at least two issues:

**Did not wait on `base.SerializeToStreamAsync`**

You created a new task, but you did not wait until the base class completed writing to the compressed stream in the task. So you could send unpredictable content to server.

**Did not override `Content-Length`**

`MultipartFormDataContent` calculates length of content based on data not compressed, since you have compressed data, you must re-compute length for the compressed data.

Frankly, I don't think you need to inherit from `MultipartFormDataContent` to make it compressed. Instead, you could compress the entire `MultipartFormDataContent` in a wrapper `HttpContent`:

```
public class GzipCompressedContent : HttpContent
{
    private readonly HttpContent _content;
    
    public GzipCompressedContent(HttpContent content)
    {
        // Copy original headers
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in content.Headers)
        {
            Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");        
        _content = content;     
    }
    
    protected override async Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            // Compress the entire original content
            await _content.CopyToAsync(gzip);
        }       
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        // Content-Lenght is optional, so set to -1
        length = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var test = new TestClass();

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    form.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)), "value");

    var compressed = new GzipCompressedContent(form);

    var result = await client.PostAsync(..., compressed);
}
```

#### Server side

Your server needs to support compressed stream.

For example, by default, ASP.NET Core does not support compressed request, if you send GZip compressed request to an ASP.NET Core application, you will see exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component. 
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The above exception happens in action invocation pipeline before any controller action takes place. So controller actions in this case could not be reached.

To fix such, you will need to enable server side request decompression support.

If you are using ASP.NET Core, check out [this nuget package](https://github.com/alexanderkozlenko/aspnetcore-request-decompression).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the issue, but if it is that your request isn't getting to the server, while your "normal" POST requests are, then I think that I found your problem.

I think that the issue is that your server doesn't know what Content-Type is coming to it. I literally copy-pasted your code, but added

```cs
Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-gzip");
```

to `GzipMultipartContent.cs` ctor.

After I added the type, I was hitting my breakpoint in the localhost server.

Source: [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

> In requests, (such as POST or PUT), the client tells the server what type of data is actually sent.